# Blocking pip install in JupyterHub

Tags: python, kubernetes, pip, jupyter, jupyterhub

Is it possible to block pip installs on JupyterHub instances? Is there a certain port pip runs through that I can block?

Comment: You can discourage it, but I don't think you can stop someone determined from installing external packages one way or another. What's your goal?

Comment: how is this related to the kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

JupyterHub internally spawns an instance of Jupyter Notebook so ideally, you would be looking to block the pip commands on Jupyter Notebook.

You have two solutions as per the best of my knowledge since I've faced a similar issue.

1) Write your custom kernel wherein you could choose to not have certain commands which aren't required for your use case.

OR

2) If it fits your use case, you could simply choose to delete the shell itself.

Refer to my answer here for the steps: [Turn off magic from jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402957/turn-off-magic-from-jupyter-notebook/47050743#47050743)

Ideally, if you are running such a multi-user environment, I'd suggest using Docker.

To run JupyterHub with Docker, check out this link for more info on Universities / Institutes running JupyterHub - https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gallery-jhub-deployments.html